# IEnumerable to IReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I have `IEnumerable<Object>` and need to pass to a method as a parameter but this method takes `IReadOnlyCollection<Object>`

Is it possible to convert `IEnumerable<Object>` to `IReadOnlyCollection<Object>` ?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

One way would be to construct a list, and call [`AsReadOnly()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on it:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<Object> rdOnly = orig.ToList().AsReadOnly();
```

This produces [`ReadOnlyCollection<object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx), which implements `IReadOnlyCollection<Object>`.

**Note:** Since `List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` as well, the call to `AsReadOnly()` is optional. Although it is possible to call your method with the result of `ToList()`, I prefer using `AsReadOnly()`, so that the readers of my code would see that the method that I am calling has no intention to modify my list. Of course they could find out the same thing by looking at the signature of the method that I am calling, but it is nice to be explicit about it.

Comment: `.AsReadOnly()` does have its uses. If you just return `List<T>` someone can do a `rdOnly is IList<T>` and it will return `true`, if you do `.AsReadOnly()` it will return `false`. If I don't know if my consumer could potentially try to cast my result in to a mutable interface I often do a `.AsReadOnly()` before I return the result.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain this is a very important security feature to mention!

Comment: Could you call `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToList().AsReadOnly()` ?

Comment: @MassDotNet You could, because arrays implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: Thought so -- that's what I'm already doing.  I just wanted to make sure there wasn't any errant behavior invited by doing so (e.g. screwing up sort order).

Comment: Is there a way to do this the opposite? Convert IReadOnlyCollection to IEnumerable?

Comment: @BenjaminSalerno `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can plug it into any place where an `IEnumerable<T>` is needed.

Comment: i stummbled upon this while trying to check if as IReadOnlyCollection<object> casting works on an IEnumerable but turns out only when i do a ToList() first, but an enumerable returned by LinQ( non DB) is giving back null on casting to "as IReadonlyCollection<object>"

Answer (score 16):

Since the other answers seem to steer in the direction of wrapping the collections in a *truly* read-only type, let me add this.

I have rarely, if ever, seen a situation where the caller is *so scared* that an `IEnumerable<T>`-taking method might maliciously try to cast that `IEnumerable<T>` back to a `List` or other mutable type, and start mutating it. *Cue organ music and evil laughter!*

No. If the code you are working with is even remotely reasonable, then if it asks for a type that only has read functionality (`IEnumerable<T>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`...), it will only read.

**Use `ToList()` and be done with it.**

As a side note, if you are creating the method in question, it is generally best to ask for no more than an `IEnumerable<T>`, indicating that you "just want a bunch of items to read". Whether or not you need its `Count` or need to enumerate it multiple times is an implementation detail, and is certainly prone to change. If you need multiple enumeration, simply do this:

```
items = items as IReadOnlyCollection<T> ?? items.ToList(); // Avoid multiple enumeration
```

This keeps the responsibility where it belongs (as locally as possible) and the method signature clean.

When *returning* a bunch of items, on the other hand, I prefer to return an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Why? The goal is to give the caller something that fulfills reasonsable expectations - no more, no less. Those expectations are usually that the collection is materialized and that the `Count` is known - precisely what `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` provides (and a simple `IEnumerable<T>` does not). By being no more specific than this, our contract matches expectations, and the method is still free to change the underlying collection. (In contrast, if a method returns a `List<T>`, it makes me wonder what context there is that I should want to index into the list and mutate it... and the answer is usually "none".)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to dasblinkenlight's answer, to prevent the caller casting to **List<T>**, instead of doing `orig.ToList().AsReadOnly()`, the following might be better:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<object> rdOnly = Array.AsReadOnly(orig.ToArray());
```

It's the same number of method calls, but one takes the other as a parameter instead of being called on the return value.

Comment: This might even be faster!

Comment: @florien why might it even faster? Could you explain?

Comment: @snr Well, to be honest, I could not back it with a reasonable explanation. Somehow I believe that here, where the only difference is whether the type is first converted to an array or a list, arrays and working with them is more integrated into the language, and since the collection is not to be changed, list has no advantage here. Though it can indeed be that this all is optimised by the compiler.